# Problems with obtaining Wikipedia token

Tags: jquery, wikipedia-api

I am trying to obtain Wikipedia edit token using this code:

```
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&format=json&callback=?", function (data) {
    console.log( data );
});
```

However, I am receiving this error:

> "Tokens may not be obtained when the same-origin policy is not applied."

What is the correct way to get the token using jQuery?

**EDIT:** I have tried following approaches (based on comments):

- Removing callback=? and adding origin=* - that throws the original token error
- Using modified example from [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CORS):

  ```
  $.ajax( {
   url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
   data: {
    action: 'query',
    meta: 'tokens',
    format: 'json',
    origin: 'http://example.com'
   },
   xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
   },
   dataType: 'json'
  }).done( function ( data ) {
   console.log(data);
  });
  ```

  This returns the Cross-Origin error mentioned in comments.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wikipedia's API, but have you followed their documentation closely? If you can get it working with JavaScript you can post the JS here and someone will be able to translate it to jQuery for you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have working javascript code (I don't even know if there is some simple way to do this using pure JS). The documentation regarding tokens can be found [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Tokens), the main page of the documentation is [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/API:Main_page). Thank you for your interest in the question.

Comment: Remove `&callback=?`. You have to be logged in.

Comment: @Termininja Thanks, but that throws another error: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&format=json. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)`.

Comment: Also, do I really need to be logged in? Shouldn't I get "+\\" as a reply when not logged in?

Comment: Could the following be a solution to the CORS error https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CORS add origin=*

Comment: You can't get a MediaWiki edit token cross-domain. It would be the ultimate CSRF vulnerability if you could.

Comment: So it's impossible for external application to obtain edit token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible.

Do you really want any site anywhere on the internet to be able to use your browser/IP address/Wikipedia login details to edit Wikipedia? I certainly don't.

Mediawiki (the software behind Wikipedia) is set up to prevent this. Basically, you can't perform any state-changing action (e.g. edits, logging in, anything else that changes anything) from a different domain. You may essentially only do requests that get information without changing anything. You can only use the Mediawiki API from the browser if you are (a) making the request from that specific wiki's domain or (b) the wiki is configured to support *your particular server* using CORS.

From [the API page on data formats](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats#Callback_restrictions):

> When using JSON in callback mode, a number of things are disabled for security:
>
> - Tokens cannot be obtained (so state-changing actions aren't possible)
>     The client is treated as an anonymous user (i.e. not logged in) for all purposes, even after logging in through `action=login`
> - This means that things that require additional rights, such as `rcprop=patrolled`, won't work unless anonymous users are allowed to use them

A request using CORS will also not be possible for any state-changing action ([see "cross-site requests"](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests)) unless specifically enabled for your domain.

For all of which I say "thank goodness".

Comment: If you want to make edits or other state-changing actions in the name of whoever edits your webpage, you can use [OAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth/For_Developers) (which has security mechanisms built in to ensure you can only do things the user would approve of).